# When to use method cascading in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, methods

From my understanding of Pythonic coding style (and in particular PEP20), code must be simple and readable. With this in mind is method cascading deemed Pythonic?

For example, lets say we have a `Cascade` class:

```
class Cascade(object):
  def __init__(self, pythonic):
    self.question = 'Is this Pythonic?'
    self.answer = pythonic

  def copy(self):
    import copy
    return copy.deepcopy(self)

  def is_pythonic(self):
    return self.answer
```

Then which is better:

```
>>> cas = Cascade(False)
>>> cas.copy().is_pythonic()
 False
```

Or else:

```
>>> cas1 = Cascade(False)
>>> cas2 = cas1.copy()
>>> cas2.is_pythonic()
 False
```

The first option is in my opinion more readable as my eyes sweep left to right - almost akin to reading a book, whereas the second keeps one simple statement per line (which admittedly is also highly readable).

### EDIT

Following the useful comments by [Haleemur Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2570261/haleemur-ali), [Lutz Horn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907906/lutz-horn) and [claust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4541251/claust), I would like to rephrase the question to the broader **"When should I use method cascading in Python?"**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are acceptable.

Long chains get harder to read, so try to avoid really long chains.

Also, if you break it down to separate statements, you might find reuse, i.e

```
c = cas1.copy()
c.method1()
c.method2()
c.is_pythonic()
```

*edit following comment by @claust*
Also note that cascading is useful in anonymous objects: I use it a lot in GUI programming, where you may create and grid an object without needing to reference it later: tkinter.Label("label").grid(row=0, column=0)

Comment: Good point - the ability to reuse the object elsewhere is definitely a strong argument for the single statement option.

Comment: Also note that cascading is useful in anonymous objects: I use it a lot in GUI programming, where you may create and grid an object without needing to reference it later: `tkinter.Label("label").grid(row=0, column=0)`

Comment: @claust, you're right, i'll update my answer for anyone stumbling on this question.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you need the result of

```
cas.copy()
```

later, you must use the second approach. If you don't need it and *only* want to call `is_pythonic()` on it, the first approach is fine.